# How to populate SQLite database on start of emulator in my Android App.

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have an excel file with 4 fields that I would like to use to populate the database when the emulator is first used. Previously, I used to store the database file directly on the phone, but it would be easier if these items were populated on creation. How can I read from an excel file or text file and populate the database when the emulator starts up?

Comment: I recommend creating a SQLite database with your data on your development machine, then packaging that database with your app using `SQLiteAssetHelper`: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a spreadsheet like :-

[image]

That has been been saved, using file explorer, as a **CSV** file named **Book1.csv** to the **application's** **asset** folder (create the folder named assets if need be) e.g.

[image]

i.e. `D:\Android_Applications\LoadDataFromExcel\app\src\main\assets`

And a DatabaseHelper (i.e subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper) as per :-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "mydb";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String MYDATA_TBL = "mydata";
    public static final String MYDATA_ID_COL = "_id";
    public static final String MYDATA_NAME_COL = "_name";
    public static final String MYDATA_AMOUNT_COL = "_amount";
    public static final String MYDATA_DATE_COL = "_date";
    public static final String MYDATA_DESCRIPTION_COL = "_description";

    private static final String TBLCREATESQL =
            "CREATE TABLE " + MYDATA_TBL +
                    "(" +
                    MYDATA_ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    MYDATA_NAME_COL + " TEXT," +
                    MYDATA_AMOUNT_COL + " INTEGER," +
                    MYDATA_DATE_COL + " TEXT, " +
                    MYDATA_DESCRIPTION_COL + " TEXT" +
                    ")";

    private SQLiteDatabase mDB;


    public DatabaseHelper(Context ccontext) {
        super(ccontext, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(TBLCREATESQL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public long insertRow(String name, int amount, String date, String description) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(MYDATA_NAME_COL,name);
        cv.put(MYDATA_AMOUNT_COL,amount);
        cv.put(MYDATA_DATE_COL,date);
        cv.put(MYDATA_DESCRIPTION_COL,description);
        return mDB.insert(MYDATA_TBL,null,cv);
    }
}
```

Then you could have something based upon :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper dbh;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dbh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        loadExternalData();
    }


    private void loadExternalData() {

        InputStream importdata;
        BufferedReader br;
        String line;
        String[] splitdata;
        int linecount = 0;

        final String tag = "loadExternalData";
        try {
            importdata = this.getAssets().open("Book1.csv");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(tag,"Error opening asset file");
            return;
        }
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(importdata));
        try {
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                // Skip column headings
                if (linecount++ > 0) {
                     splitdata = line.split(",");
                     dbh.insertRow(
                             splitdata[0],
                             new Integer(splitdata[1]),
                             splitdata[2],
                             splitdata[3]
                     );
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(tag,"IO Error reading data at line " + (linecount + 1));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***Note! this is very rudimentary and rather an in-principle demonstration, e.g. it wouldn't cope with commas within the data, and it would create a new set of rows each time that it is run***

#### The Resultant Database :-

[image]

#### Edit - Changes to only add rows once (but allow new data to be added)

1) Add new method to the DatabaseHelper class :-

```
public boolean ifRowExists(String name, int amount, String date, String description) {
    Cursor csr = mDB.query(MYDATA_TBL,null,
            MYDATA_NAME_COL + "=? AND " +
                    MYDATA_AMOUNT_COL + "=? AND " + 
                    MYDATA_DATE_COL + "=? AND " + 
                    MYDATA_DESCRIPTION_COL + "=?",
            new String[]{name,Integer.toString(amount), date, description},
            null,null,null
    );
    boolean rv = csr.getCount() > 0;
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```

2) Amend the `loadExternalData` method in the invoking class to check if the row being inserted exists :-

```
private void loadExternalData() {

    InputStream importdata;
    BufferedReader br;
    String line;
    String[] splitdata;
    int linecount = 0;

    final String tag = "loadExternalData";
    try {
        importdata = this.getAssets().open("Book1.csv");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(tag,"Error opening asset file");
        return;
    }
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(importdata));
    try {
        while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            // Skip column headings
            if (linecount++ > 0) {
                splitdata = line.split(",");
                if (!dbh.ifRowExists(splitdata[0], new Integer(splitdata[1]), splitdata[2], splitdata[3])) {
                    dbh.insertRow(
                            splitdata[0],
                            new Integer(splitdata[1]),
                            splitdata[2],
                            splitdata[3]
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(tag,"IO Error reading data at line " + (linecount + 1));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to store the data correctly, but it adds a new set of rows like you said. Any advice on how to only call the method once?

Comment: @RichardAguilar I've edited the answer with one solution that checks the data to see if it already exists. However, this will read the data each time the App is run. It has the advantage that new data can be introduced, but the disadvantage that it will frequently read the data  and check for the existence of the row needlessly. Personally I'd consider an alternative such as having a table with a single row to indicate that the data has been read.